# Typing on a UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, ios8

I'm building an iOS 8-only app that allows me to type notes anywhere on an image. Currently, when the user taps anywhere on the UIImageView, the app presents a modal textview to allow the user to type the text they want added to the photo. When the user taps "Done" in the modal view, the text is added using the following drawing code...

```
+ (UIImage *)drawText:(NSString *)text 
             inImage:(UIImage *)image 
             atPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
    [text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withFont:font]; 
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

It works, but it's not ideal because the user can't see the placement of the text until after they've added the text. Ideally, the user can type directly on the UIImageView without having to type the text in a modal textview. How can I take the modal view out of the process and allow the user to type directly on the UIImageView?

Comment: Add a transparent UITextField

Answer (score 2):

You could add a transparent UIView that contains a UITextField and well as editing buttons.  This would be placed on above the UIImageView after a user tap.

The UIView could contain editing items such as Done, Clear and Drag. User could also tap existing text and allow them to edit the text.